# Route53 claims no nameservers after transferring dns records

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I had a domain and dns records on one AWS account, which was all working fine. I have since transferred everything to another AWS account. The domain was done by request from AWS customer service, and the DNS was done by downloading a json containing the records and uploading it to the new account via the command line, following amazon's instructions for doing so.

This seemed to have worked, except that I wasn't receiving mail, and the certificates I requested have been 'pending verification' for 24 hours. I did an "MX check", and the result was that there are no nameservers for my domain. This is strange, as the nameservers are definitely present in Route53, and were auto generated by amazon in this account (the transfer procedure is to create a new route53 hosted zone, *delete* NS and SOA data from the json, and then upload it, so the NS and SOA are *not* from my previous account).

I did this about 28 hours ago. Now, *I know* that, in theory, it can take 72 hours or whatever to propagate, but in two years of using AWS, I've *never* had to wait for DNS to propagate for more than five minutes, hence this question!

Comment: This seems like something you should contact AWS support about, they are generally fairly quick to reply and would know more details about any underlying issues you are facing

Comment: @Deiv I'm only on the basic support plan, which apparently doesn't give technical support :/

Comment: I see, it might be worth submitting a support case anyways, maybe they can point you in the right direction. Otherwise, hopefully someone can help you out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are expecting too much from AWS. They only generally get involved when you don't have the permissions to do it yourself, like moving a domain from one AWS Account to another.

As long as the domain appears in the new AWS Account, you should be able to sort it out yourself.

1. Check that you see the domain name in **Route53 > Registered Domains**.
2. Check that you see the zone in **Route53 > Hosted Zones** with the correct domain name.
3. In the Host Zone, make a note of the **NS Records**.
4. Back to the Registered Domain, make sure that the **Name Servers** are the same as the Zone NS Records.
5. Back to the Zone, make sure that the **MX Record** is correct for the Mail Service that you use.

At this point you should be able to receive email.

If you have created new Certificates, or anything that needed email confirmation, go to the service and re-request verification.

Comment: It turns out that the name servers listed in the "Registered Domains" section, were not the same as those generated in Route53. Thanks!