# AWS HostedZone not doing anything after transfer from one AWS account to the other (Route53 claims no nameservers)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I transferred an AWS Route53 domain from one AWS account to another - both are unrelated, not part of any federation or organization etc.

Now, when I use the related hostedzone to try and add entries to this domain, nothing happens.

In fact, it does not update in `who.is`'s records at all. They remain as the old records, at least NS-wise.

[image: Attempt to change DNS entries fails...]

[image: Attempted DNS entries...]

I opened a case with AWS support and they tell me every time that someone from the R53 team will get into contact with me, but I fear the help won't come soon enough.

To confirm: I can 100% guarantee that the hostedzone *is* the one for my domain. How do I know this? Well, when I make a certificate for the route53 domain in ACM and click "create route53 records", those ACM validation entries are added to that hostedzone.

If nobody has any ideas, I'll release the name of the domain, but I'm scared right now that it's in some kind of technical limbo and could somehow be compromised.

Comment: Marking as a duplicate, thanks for the link: [Route53 claims no nameservers after transferring dns records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399054/route53-claims-no-nameservers-after-transferring-dns-records)

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been solved.

[Route53 claims no nameservers after transferring dns records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399054/route53-claims-no-nameservers-after-transferring-dns-records)

The above link has the answer - make **sure** that the nameservers present in `registered domains > yourdomainname` are the *same* ones that are in the NS record.

[image: These were wrong before.]

The above nameserver records were different to what was in the "NS" DNS entry in the hostedzone. Don't ask me why. If anyone knows, please leave a comment.